# PySide6 segmentation fault on Ubuntu 18.04 (Relink issue)

Tags: python, linux, qt, ubuntu, pyside

This script is from the [Qt for Python](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python) page:

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

                                                     

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    label = QLabel("Hello World", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    label.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I installed PySide with `pip3 install pyside6`, my python version is `3.6.9`, my ubuntu version is `18.04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it in a virtual environment? Maybe the system-wide installation make some pre-existing libraries interfere.

Choose the folder where you want to install your virtual environment

```
user@pc:~/$ python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/virtualenvironment/my_venv
```

Activate the new virtual env:

```
user@pc:~/$ source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate
```

Install (locally) PySide6:

```
(my_venv) user@pc:~/$ pip3 install pyside6
```

Run the script from the virtual environment:

```
(my_venv) user@pc:~/$ python3 my_qt_script.py
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, though I had to use `PySide2` instead.